# When does a device get a 512B request from the filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, block, linux-device-driver

Am new to linux and have been doing a bit of reading. But am a little confused about the following. Can the device receive a request for a single 512B sector ? Under what conditions does this happen? From what I understand , while the sector size defines the smallest unit a device can be addressed by , the FS usually has a block size of 4K(smallest unit of access for the fs) . So this means most(all) commands are addressed by the FS on a 4k granularity.

1. Can a file system generate traffic for <4K(1-7 512bytes) from application traffic?
2. Is there some file system meta data that can cause this kind of traffic?
3. If we align the partition to a 4k boundary, will the device always get commands aligned on 4k boundaries?

Comment: *"Can the device receive a request for a single 512B sector ?"* -- Depends on the *"device"*.  Since the 1980s the typical mass storage device has a physical block (aka sector) size of 512 bytes.  As HDD capacity balloons into the terabyte range and for SSD compatibility, the sector size has evolved to 4KB.  *"the FS usually has a block size of 4K"* -- That's a logical block size.  The filesystem is a higher layer that can deal with a device driver for a block device that has a different physical block size.  *"traffic"* -- Do you mean "requests"?

Comment: yes by the traffic I mean requests to the device.  While 4KB is becoming popular, it still isn't the de-facto sector size for most SSD's (they support the 512e format)  ... So my question is can the file system issue a request to the device which is just a single 512B read/write . Under what circumstances can this happen ? Given the logical block size of the FS is 4K will all requests to a device with 512e format also be n*512 where n is a multiple of 8(so all 4K aligned commands?) . Thanks !

Comment: *"can the file system issue a request to the device which is just a single 512B read/write"* -- Block devices such as HDD, SDD and flash drives use the ATAPI interface.  The fundamental unit of transfer is a sector of 512 bytes.  So the answer is "yes".  *"Under what circumstances can this happen ?"* -- You can review the actual filesystem code in the Linux kernel source e.g. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/  Standard ATAPI for 512 bytes/sector device has no requirement of "4K alignment" for multi-sector I/O.

Comment: Thank you . This helps a lot. Will get back if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a variety of reasons (assuming your disks expose a logical sector size of 512 bytes) because you send a direct request for 512 bytes correctly aligned outside of the filesystem:

Some cases when this can happen during general usage:

- Reading an old style MBR partition table (which fits in 512 bytes at the start of the disk)
- Rewriting the bootloader or because you told it to happen
- Trying to read the smallest sized sector from a broken disk with 512 byte sectors